# Handle JavaScript errors

Tags: javascript, exception, handleerror

I'm working on a NodeJs project. I come across with a thought that how can I differentiate an error occur in operational process (for example: system is out of memory) from a programmer error (for example: syntax error)

Does anyone have a tip for this?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Syntax errors that are not immediately observable when starting the application would be treated the same as operational errors, wouldn't they?

Comment: Every uncaught operational error is a programmer mistake :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like `process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {throw err})` it will catch and throw any uncaught errors in your code.
Also, have a look at this for more information: https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors